# баг с комментарием после RowNum

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Если в запросе `SELECT` используем функцию псевдостолбца `RowNum` без псевдонима а после него сразу пишем `-- какой-то комментарий`, то в результат попадёт столбец под неявно сгенерированным псевдонимом = ("RowNum--" + текст комментария) с удалением пробелов и приведением символов к верхнему регистру.
Пример-иллюстрация:

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT DUMMY, ROWNUM --12 some 34 thing
    FROM   DUAL
    ) TestTable
WHERE TestTable."ROWNUM" > 0                 --ОШИБКА
```

рабочий вариант обращения к столбцу по псевдониму:

```
--WHERE TestTable."ROWNUM--12some34thing" > 0  --всё ещё ОШИБКА
WHERE TestTable."ROWNUM--12SOME34THING" > 0  --корректно только в верхнем регистре!
```

Аналогично и для `/*...*/` многострочного комментария.
Это не проблема (по крайней мере моя), просто интересно :) но может кому-то нервов стоить, он не гуглится почему-то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне не удалось найти объяснение всего этого целиком в одном месте. Тем не менее, по частям большая часть гуглится.

1. `ROWNUM` - [псевдостолбец](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255). Тот эффект, который вы заметили, применяется к любым выражениям. Столбец сам по себе имеет имя, а выражение - нет, поэтому имя для выражения генерируется, если не задано явно. Например:

   ```
   select dummy, dummy x, 2*2, 2*2 /*duplicate*/, rownum, rownum -- preved
     from dual;

   D X        2*2 2*2/*DUPLICATE*/     ROWNUM ROWNUM--PREVED
   - - ---------- ---------------- ---------- --------------
   X X          4                4          1              1
   ```

   Правила генерации нагуглить пока не удалось. Найду - добавлю. Если кто знает - можете смело править ответ.
2. Есть [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) - там написано про верхний регистр:

   > Nonquoted identifiers are not case sensitive. Oracle interprets them as uppercase. Quoted identifiers are case sensitive.

Comment: логично, конечно -- но я почему-то ожидал, что комментарии будут игнорироваться; про то, что если подобный однострочный комментарий в области `SELECT` завершается символом тире, тогда это неявно полностью прячет следующую строку запроса при его обработке имеет смысл написать, как считаете? :)

Comment: Так это просто обычное поведение для комментариев, как и везде. Ну или я не понял, о чем вы.

Comment: В итоге исправление сводится к заменен `ROWNUM --12 some 34 thing` на `ROWNUM AS ROWNUM --12 some 34 thing`